# I need to get the line number which has the highest value

Tags: awk, sed, perl

I have a txt file as follows

```
 1  8.92
 2  9.99
 3  9.57
 4  9.63
 5  9.57
 6  9.51
 7  7.84
 8  7.95
 9  9.44
10  9.58
11  9.94
12  10.20
13  9.35
```

I need the line number of the highest value. How can I get that?
e.g. the answer for this data will be

12    10.20

Comment: sort -rn test.txt | awk '!x[$2]++'  
        sort -k2 -n test1.txt | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: Are the line numbers part of the input file or not? Also, please *[edit]* your question to add extra information. it is hard to read and easy to miss in the comments.

Comment: yes or no. I need both. Line numbers may be part of the file or may not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After copy-paste your example, I did it with:

```
sort -k2 -nr filename.txt | head -1
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid sorting, you could do:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || $2 > max {number = $1; max = $2}
     END {if (NR) print number, max}' < file
```

or if the input only contains one column and you want to know the number of the line that has the maximum value:

```
awk 'NR == 1 || $1 > max {number = NR; max = $1}
     END {if (NR) print number, max}' < file
```

Comment: The OP wants the line number though, not just the line.

Comment: @terdon, from what I understand of the question, the _line number_ is the first column in the file. That would seem to be confirmed by the fact that Zumo's answer was accepted.

Comment: Oh. Huh, fair enough. I had assumed the OP was adding them for our convenience.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with `sort -rn -k2 test`, where `test` is the name of the file containing your example data.

```
12 10.20
7 7.84
8 7.95
1 8.92
13 9.35
9 9.44
6 9.51
3 9.57
5 9.57
10 9.58
4 9.63
11 9.94
2 9.99
```

And you can get the line number with:

```
sort -rn -k2 test | awk '{print $2}' | grep $(head -1) -n test
```

output:

```
12:12 10.20
```

Comment: you're right, I've edited my answer

Comment: that's the highest value of the sorted output, it's `10.20` in the example, I grep it against the file to get the line number

Comment: no, it's not, try it yourself and see

Comment: `$(head -1)` stores the output of `head -1` in a variable, which is then used by `grep`. My example works - tested on Mac OS X and Debian Jessie. I'm ending my discussion with you, as it is becoming pointless.

Comment: You're sorting lexically so "14 100.1" will *not* show up as the highest value. You need to pass sort the `-n -r` options to sort numerically

Comment: @terdon have you tested it? Create a file named `test`, add the contents used in the example and execute `sort -rn -k2 test | awk '{print $2}' | grep $(head -1) -n test`. What happens?

Comment: I'll be damned! You're quite right, apparently the pipe will pass data to `head` before running the `grep`. Huh. Fair enough, my bad.

Comment: @don_crissti I was equally certain but, it turns out, we're the ones who should test. Apparently, the `$(head -1)` is taking input from the pipe and successfully searches for the first line of output from `sort` in the test file.

Comment: @terdon, note that it wouldn't work with `zsh`. See `: | echo "$(ls -l /proc/self/fd)"` for instance. `: | {echo "$(ls -l /proc/self/fd)"}` would be OK.

Comment: @don_crissti sure, and it also needs to process the file twice. I'm not saying this is a good approach. Just pointing out that the `| grep $(head -1)` bit does seem to work in bash, which suggests that Dimitar didn't deserve our scathing remarks.

Comment: I suggest we end the discussion.